# react mobx - store return Proxy object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have the following state class:

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class AppState {
  @observable user;
  @observable pToken;

  constructor() {
    this.user = {};
    this.pToken = localStorage.getItem('pToken');
  }

  async fetchData(query) {

    const body = JSON.stringify({ query, });
    const response = await axios.post('url', body, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        token: localStorage.getItem('pToken')
      }
    });

    const user = response.data.data.user;
    console.log('Got user', user);
    this.setUser(user);
  }

  @action setUser(user) {
    this.user = user;
  }
}
```

and in my component:

```
@inject('store')
@observer
export default class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.store = this.props.store.appState;
    }

    render() {
        const { user } = this.store;
        console.log('store', this.store);

        return (
            <header className='header'>
                User - {user.username}
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the state `user` property returns a `Proxy` object, while the `user` log shows the user object. Any idea what I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everything is working as intended, MobX v5 relies on proxies under the hood so when you log observable objects it usually shows some internal implementation.

For more user-friendly output you can use `toJS` MobX method like that `console.log(toJS(user))` or just destructure user object `console.log({ ...user })`

`toJS` docs: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/tojson.html

Comment: I don't want to use `toJS` which I read to be an expensive operation, every time I'm trying to access an object in the store

Comment: You don't need to use it to access, just to log things to the console when you develop. To access you use regular dot notation like you already do `user.username`

Comment: Oh it confused me! I did `console.log(user)` and saw a proxy, but `user.id` actually works without an expensive operation like toJS! Thanks!

Comment: For primitive types it works (like strings/numbers) which are not holding the value by references. For objects/array which hold the reference, it returns the proxy.